# If $\mu$ is atomless then its c.d.f. is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove this property. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$ and $F$ its c.d.f. Then $F$ is right-continuous and non-decreasing.

> **Theorem:** If $\mu$ is [atomless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures) then $F$ is continuous.

---

**My attempt:** Assume the contrary that $F$ is not continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$. Then $F$ is not left-continuous at $a$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \neq a$, $x_n \nearrow a$, and $F(x_n) \not\to F(a)$. Because $F$ is non-decreasing, there is $\alpha < F(a)$ such that $F(x_n) \nearrow \alpha$.

By continuity of measure from below
$$
\mu ((-\infty, a)) = \lim_n \mu ((-\infty, x_n]) = \lim_n F(x_n) =\alpha.
$$

It follows that
$$
\mu (\{a\}) = \mu ((-\infty, a]) - \mu ((-\infty, a)) = F(a)- \alpha >0.
$$

Hence $a$ is an atom, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is correct.