# No Atoms and pushforward measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

I have the following statement from the first Chapter "Couplings and changes of variables" of the book [Optimal Transport: Old and New by Cédric Villani](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)

> The increasing rearrangement on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mu, \nu$ be two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$; define their cumulative distribution functions by
> $$
> F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x d \mu, \quad G(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y d \nu .
> $$
> Further define their right-continuous inverses by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &F^{-1}(t)=\inf \{x \in \mathbb{R} ; \quad F(x)>t\} \\
> &G^{-1}(t)=\inf \{y \in \mathbb{R} ; \quad G(y)>t\}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> and set
> $$
> T=G^{-1} \circ F .
> $$
> If $\mu$ does not have atoms, then $T_{\#} \mu=\nu$. This rearrangement is quite simple, explicit, as smooth as can be, and enjoys good geometric properties.

Why is that "If $\mu$ does not have atoms, then $T_{\#} \mu=\nu$"? Why do we need that $\mu$ does not have atoms?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the left-continuous inverse $H^\leftarrow(p)=\inf\{x:H(x)\geq p\}$.

We know that if $Z$ has cdf $H$ (which is right-continuous and nondecreasing) and $U\sim \textrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ then:

1. if $H$ is continuous, then $H(Z)\sim U$;
2. $H^\leftarrow (x)\leq y \iff H(y)\geq x$

You can find these facts in [McNeil et al.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantitative-Risk-Management-Techniques-Princeton/dp/0691166277) (Proposition 5.2.(2) and Proposition A.3.(iv)).

If $X\sim \mu$ and it does not have atoms, then [this implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493339/if-mu-is-atomless-then-its-c-d-f-is-continuous) it has a continuous cdf $F$. We can state:
$$P(T(X)\leq y)=P(G^{\leftarrow}(F(X))\leq y)=P(F(X)\leq G(y))=G(y)$$
Now since $P(T(X)\leq y)=(T_\#\mu)((-\infty,y])$ and the measures $T_\#\mu,\nu$ agree on an $\cap$-stable generator of the Borel sets on the real line, we can state that $T_\#\mu=\nu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not quite familiar with this area, so please allow me to ask some questions to make sure that I really understand: So the non-atomic property implies the continuity of the CDF of F which gives us $F(X)\sim U$. But how do you get the last equality? ($P(U\leq G(y))=G(y)$)

Comment: The last equality is the value of the [cdf of a uniform rv on $(0,1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) at point $G(y)$ @Tab1e